# React.memo is not working on FlatList item

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I'm fairly new to React Native and I'm trying to implement a List for my app with `FlatList`. The list is dynamic where I'm fetching 20 items at a time from the local DB.

Issue -

- After rendering around 50-60 list items, if I scroll from top to bottom or vice-versa the items re-render. The items do not render again if there are around 40 items in list.
- To tackle this, I used `React.Memo` but it is not working.

I have created a Sandbox, where I'm rendering a very simple list, I can see the re-rendering message if I scroll the list up and down.

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-napier-wyc62o?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Try adding `keyExtractor` prop in FlatList.

Comment: @BilalHussain It is there in the prop.